# Hibernate: delete the parent/owner while keeping the child in one-to-one relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I have two Entity Classes: UserConfirmation and User, they are one-to-one relationship using the following annotated code:

**the Parent/Owner Entity (UserConfirmation):**

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userConfirmation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user;
```

**the Child Entity (User):**

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_confirm_id")
@JsonBackReference
private UserConfirmation userConfirmation;
```

With the current `Cascade.ALL`, when I delete the UserConfirmation, its associated User also gets deleted, which I do not want. I would like to keep the User after deleting the UserConfirmation.

**I've tried the following:**

1. Set the user to null before deleting UserConfirmation: `userConfirmation.setUser(null);` but this gives a NullPointerException
2. tried Cascade.REMOVE and almost everything on Cascade, but none works.

Your help is appreciated as always :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot delete a **parent** without removing all **child-side** parent Foreign Key associations.

In your example you say that the `UserConfirmation` is the parent and the `User` is the child, but this is not correct.

The parent side is the one that's independent of the other side existance. In your case the `User` should be the **parent** and the `UserConfirmation` should be the **child** side.

So, the `User` has:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private UserConfirmation userConfirmation;
```

It's the parent that cascades [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/) to children.

And the UserConfirmation is the child, yet it's the owner-side:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonBackReference
private User user;
```

Now you can delete a `UserConfirmation` while leaving the `User` untouched.

Answer (score 0):

You used cascade on wrong side.

From `OneToOne.cascade` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#cascade()):

> (Optional) The operations that must be cascaded to the **target** of the association.

In JPA you define cascade operations on opposite side than you would in SQL.

Your code should actually look:

the Parent/Owner Entity (UserConfirmation):

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userConfirmation")
@JsonManagedReference
private User user;
```

the Child Entity (User):

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_confirm_id")
@JsonBackReference
private UserConfirmation userConfirmation;
```

Comment: how do you define the target of the association? It's bidirectional

Comment: Target depends where you put annotation. If you put in class `User` class on `userConfirmation ` field then it points it to `UserConfirmation`. Therefore instance of `UserConfirmation` is considered a target of the association.